# Telerik RadCalendar ASP.NET control reset date

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I use Telerik RadCalendar ASP.NET control. How I can in code reset selected date? (Set no selected Date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From their site:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/calendar/examples/programming/clientsideapi/defaultcs.aspx

```
unselectDate(date); //Takes a triplet representation of a date and if valid deselects it in the calendar.
unselectDates(dates);  //Takes an array of triplets representing dates and if valid deselects them in the calendar.
```

First you can find what dates are selected with get_selectedDates()
Then put them in the unselect method.

```
var selectedDates = get_selectedDates();
unselectDates(selectedDates);
```

If you dont know what dates are selected maybe you can reload the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear the selection server-side then this should work:

```
RadCalendarObject.SelectedDates.Clear();
```