# Clear selected Date in Radcalender

Tags: c#, winforms

I am writing an application which updates the date selected in RadCalender to a database column on click of a button.

After the button is clicked, i want to clear the selected date so that the end user selects a date before clicking the button again

I have tired using the below code, but it dosen't appear to work

```
calExpirydate.SelectedDates.Clear();
```

Comment: Is this a telerik asp RadCalendar? Yes?

Comment: it's a winform Rad Calender

Comment: Yeah it's telerik then. @user3435047 check out my answer and give it a whirl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following script:

```
var selectedDates = get_selectedDates(); //Gets the "list" of selected dates
unselectDates(selectedDates); // unselects all dates that may have been selected.
```

Code taken from: [Telerik Reset Calendar Selected Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509537/telerik-radcalendar-asp-net-control-reset-date)

### ----------------------------

```
radCal1.RemoveFocusedDate(true); //Will remove the calendar date currently selected.
```

Comment: The name get_selectedDates();does not exist in the current context. How to define it.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Telerik UI for winforms 15.2.623.0

Comment: Do you have a remove method for a singular selecteddate?

Comment: Thanks. This code worked.calExpirydate.RemoveFocusedDate(true);